# CUSTOM COMPONENT SECTION IS NOT AVAILABLE IN COMMUNITY BUILDER

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, community

I need to add a custom component (lwc) in the community, but the custom component section is not available.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add another target `lightningCommunity__Default`

Comment: thanks, that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another target `lightningCommunity__Default`